# To give access to users in group for individual OU's

Tags: windows-server-2008, groups

I have 6 users in my user group and my job is to allow each user to allow access to different OU's and not to whole Domain. And also to provide RDP access. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What does "to allow access" mean? Please do your best to ask a specific question if you want a specific answer.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear before. Consider there are 6 OU's and 6 Users. 1st user should be able to login only for 1st OU machines and so on. Hope i'm clear this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Group Policy to configure all of these settings.